# Executar sequelize migrate em um docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, sequelize-js

Olá!

Tenho meu ambiente de desenvolvimento configurado em Docker.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "teste_sequelize",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "teste do sequelize",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "clear && nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "eu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
  }
}
```

Dokerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 1234

CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    data:

services: 
    db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rafaesah
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
          - TZ=America/Bahia

    myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        ports:
          - 80:80
        environment:
          - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

    app: 
        build: .
        command: npm start
        depends_on: 
          - db
        ports: 
          - "1234:1234"
        expose:
          - "1234"
        links: 
            - db
            - myadmin
        volumes: 
            - .:/usr/app
```

config;database.js:

```
module.exports = {
  username: 'root',
  password: 'senha',
  database: 'my_db',
  host: 'db',
  port: '3306',
  dialect: 'mysql',
};
```

Quando eu executo `npm start` no terminal, e acesso as rotas via `express` a conexão é bem sucedida. Mas se abra outro terminal e tento `npx sequelize db:migrate` ele acusa `erro: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`. Se eu altero o `host` em `config/database.js` para `localhost` a `migrate` funciona.

Como configurar para funcionar a `migrate` sem ter que ficar trocando o `host` toda vez?

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

O problema de correr o migration no terminal é que o seu computador não sabe o que é `my_db`.

Há 2 alternativas para resolver isso

- Adicionar `my_db` ao arquivo hosts do seu sistema operacional (não recomendo);
- Correr os comandos a partir de um container.

Para inicializar o seu container com o bash e correr o comando de migração vc poder fazer algo como:

`docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash SUA_IMAGEM_DO_DOCKER npx sequelize db:migrate`

Outra opção é iniciar o container em modo iterativo:

`docker run -it SUA_IMAGEM_DO_DOCKER /bin/bash`